# php '&' Character makes serious issue

Tags: php, database

I make a form that receives some information from users, and send this to my server and save at database through query sending.
My problem is that When user input '&' character, then code doesn't work properly.

Query is

```
"UPDATE artist_portfolio SET Biography = '".(UsefulHelper::mysql_escape($data['Biography']))."',Profile = '".(UsefulHelper::mysql_escape($data['Profile']))."',Name = '".(UsefulHelper::mysql_escape($data['Name']))."' WHERE Artist_id = '".(UsefulHelper::mysql_escape($id))."'"
```

And UsefulHelper::mysql_escape($inp)

```
public static function mysql_escape($inp)
    {
        $inp = mb_convert_encoding($inp,'UTF-8');
        if(is_array($inp)) return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp);

        if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) {
            return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a",'&'), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z','&#38;'), $inp);
        }

        return $inp;
    }
```

If user input string which contains '&', server only recognizes characters before '&'.

For instances, '1234&dddd' => '1234'.

Another problem is... There are a huge number of codes like this. So I have to modify only UsefulHelper::mysql_escape function..

Please Help me. This problem makes me mad.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong bit of code. A `&` has special meaning **in a URL**. The problem is with whatever code you are using to generate your URLs (which is presumably some JavaScript that generates a query string by mashing strings together since a regular form submission for escape them properly).

Comment: Thank you! I solve my problem thanks to your advice.